# Is it possible (in general) to evaluate integrals of radicals not in the denominator?

Tags: calculus, integration, radicals

$$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{P(x)} dx$$

When reading about integrating the square roots of polynomials, the radical is always in the denominator. So, are there solutions when it is not?

Comment: For $P$ a polynomial of degree $2$, you can compute all integrals $\int R(x,\sqrt{P(x)})dx$, where $R(x,y)$ involves any finite number of additions, multiplications and divisions of $x,y$ and constant (is a rational function). You can use [Euler's substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) to reduce them to integrating rational functions.

Comment: See also [elliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) and [abelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_integral) integrals.